# Parsing xml content with Ruby and generate a text file

Tags: ruby, xml

How can i generate a file like:

```
Books/Jungle_Book
Books/Alice_in_Wonderland
Foods/Bacon
Foods/Kale
Foods/Eggs
```

from an XML below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.man.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Jungle_Book</members>
        <members>Alice_in_Wonderland</members>
        <name>Books</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Bacon</members>
        <members>Kale</members>
        <members>Eggs</members>
        <name>Foods</name>
    </types>
    <version>19.0</version>
</Package>
```

The number of tags like `<name>` and `<members>` vary from one xml to another, like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.man.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Jungle_Book</members>
        <members>Alice_in_Wonderland</members>
        <name>Books</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Bacon</members>
        <members>Kale</members>
        <members>Eggs</members>
        <name>Foods</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>USA</members>
        <members>UK</members>
        <members>Ireland</members>
        <members>Japan</members>
        <name>Countries</name>
    </types>
    <version>19.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: Is using Nokogiri not an option? Also when you say the tags vary, you mean the tag names or the values?

Comment: updated the question to make it more clear

Comment: I am assuming you meant the number of `<types>` and `<members>` tags vary. If the number of `<name>` tags vary then you will need to provide the desired output for that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[rexml](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/REXML.html) module from ruby stlib might help you.

below snippet,

```
require 'rexml/document'
include REXML

xmlfile = File.new("document.xml")
xmldoc = Document.new(xmlfile)

xmldoc.elements.each("Package/types") { |t|
  t.elements.each("name") { |n|
    t.elements.each("members") {
      |m| puts "#{n.text}/#{m.text}"
    }
  }
}
```

generates output like,

```
Books/Jungle_Book
Books/Alice_in_Wonderland
Foods/Bacon
Foods/Kale
Foods/Eggs
Countries/USA
Countries/UK
Countries/Ireland
Countries/Japan
```

[link to repl](https://repl.it/repls/SuddenDarkredBellsandwhistles)